# simple SQL subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

It seems im a complete idiot when it comes to SQL....

All i need is get one value from other table, but there is multiple rows with same customerId on second table.. and i would need to get one with **highest timestamp**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CUS_SETTINGS as
SELECT 
c.id as id,
c.LANG as Language,
c.ALLOWEMAIL as AllowEmail,
l.CONFIRMED as confirmed

FROM cus.CUSTOMER c
????? something with l
/
```

LEFT JOIN will bring every row so i have multiple duplicate id's
What i need is propably subquery, but i cant get it to work...

```
(SELECT CONFIRMED FROM settings WHERE ?? c.id == l.id ?? AND MAX(TIMESTAMP) )
```

i've tried many many variations of joins and subqueries.. but for some reason.. SQL is just
too confusing....

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ROW_NUMBER()` in the subquery:

```
SELECT c.id as id, c.LANG as Language, c.ALLOWEMAIL as AllowEmail,
       l.CONFIRMED as confirmed
FROM cus.CUSTOMER c JOIN
     (SELECT s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY s.timestamp DESC) as seqnum
      FROM settings s
     ) s
     ON s.id = c.id AND s.seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  You might want a `LEFT JOIN` if you want to keep all customers, even those with no settings.

Comment: it says table created, but when i try to do SELECT * FROM new view i just get 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

Comment: @Clomez . . . Nothing in this query is obviously doing any type conversion.  If it is based on this query, then you should look at the `JOIN` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions. `MAX() OVER(PARTITION BY)` clause can give you max timestamped id.

[Analytic Functions Docs 11gR2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm)

```
SELECT SECONDD.CONFIRMED
FROM CUSTOMER CU
   INNER JOIN
   (SELECT 
           *
      FROM (SELECT SECONDD.*,
                   MAX (S.TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY S.ID)
                      AS MAXTIMESTAMP
              FROM SETTINGS SECONDD)
     WHERE TIMESTAMP = MAXTIMESTAMP) SECONDD
      ON SECONDD.ID = CU.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry; while this sounds very basic, it isn't :-)

The easiest way to get the CONFIRMED for the latest TIMESTAMP in Oracle is `KEEP LAST`. E.g.:

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(confirmed) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY timestamp)
FROM settings
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

The related `CREATE VIEW` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cus_settings as
SELECT 
  c.id AS id,
  c.lang AS language,
  c.allowemail AS allowemail,
  l.last_confirmed AS confirmed
FROM cus.customer c
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    customer_id,
    MAX(confirmed) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY timestamp) AS last_confirmed
  FROM settings
  GROUP BY customer_id;
) l ON l.customer_id = c.id;
```

Or:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW cus_settings as
SELECT 
  c.id AS id,
  c.lang AS language,
  c.allowemail AS allowemail,
  (
    SELECT MAX(confirmed) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY timestamp)
    FROM settings s
    WHERE s.customer_id = c.id
  ) AS confirmed
FROM cus.customer c;
```

Comment: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values" or also known as i dont understand how to use this

Comment: Well, it seems you misplaced it somehow in your `CREATE VIEW` statement. I've updated my answer with the code.